# Hazelnut oil as a sub for olive oil

Tags: puree

I'm looking to make a pea purée but all I have is hazelnut oil. I know olive oil is the standard. Would hazelnut oil give it too much of a nutty taste?

Comment: You could go buy a cheap bottle of olive oil, and the situation wouldn't change a bit - you'd still be left with only hazelnut oil :)

Comment: It is a very proven substitute: A significant percentage of what is sold as genuine olive oil is heavily adulterated with hazelnut oil, so a recipe that doesn't work with it would be considered erroneous by many cooks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that hazelnut oil (I use roasted hazelnut oil) is a more-than-adequate replacement for olive oil. I use it in cooking, on salads, in baking and in making purées and pâtés. It does lend a nutty flavor, but it is such that it enhances rather than overwhelms the base flavor(s). If by some chance you do find it a bit too nutty, adding a few dashes of extra salt will help correct the taste. For the record, I no longer even buy olive oil anymore. That is how well the hazelnut oil works. The only drawback is that it is substantially more expensive than olive oil.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Is hazelnut oil cheaper or more expensive than olive oil? (see the comments on this question by rackandboneman, who claims cheap olive oil is often cut with hazelnut oil.)

Comment: There is the possibility that someone is buying low-grade hazelnut oil cheaply, but as a rule, if one is purchasing quality oils, olive oil is the much less expensive option of the two. I find the additional expense of the roasted hazelnut oil to be well worth the cost.